# Why does CROSS in pig flatten the data?

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-pig

I have several `pig` aliases:

```
a: {f1: long,f2: float}
b: {f1: long,f2: float}
c: {f1: long,f2: float}
```

each containing exactly one record (they are created by `foreach (group ... all) generate ...`) and I want to create a "grand summary" by merging the above into a single alias (to be `stored using JsonStorage` and collected with `hadoop fs -get` and then loaded into Python...)

For that end I do

```
grand = CROSS a b c;
```

and I get

```
grand: {a::f1: long, a::f2: float,
        b::f1: long, b::f2: float,
        c::f1: long, c::f2: float}
```

However, I would prefer to get

```
grand: {a:{(f1: long, f2: float)},
        b:{(f1: long, f2: float)},
        c:{(f1: long, f2: float)}}
```

so that the python dict loaded by `json.load()` will have dictionary values, not flat.

How do I do that?
Is it worth the effort?
Does it even make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have found out, `CROSS` just concatenates the fields of all the constituent relations. If you want them to be in bags, you have a couple of options.

The first is a little clunky but will work for you even when the relations you are `CROSS`ing have more than one record in them. You can use the `TOBAG` built-in UDF during your previous `GENERATE` statement to make each record of your relations consist of a single bag with all of the fields.

Alternately, you can use the `COGROUP` operator. Just use a dummy group value and throw it away afterwards: `FOREACH (COGROUP a BY 1, b BY 1, c BY 1) GENERATE a, b, c;`. This should give you the schema you are looking for. This one only makes sense when you know that `a`, `b`, and `c` each have just one record.

Comment: when I replaced `generate f1,f2,f3` with `generate TOBAG(f1,f2,f2)`, I got `describe` printing `{{(NULL)}}`. could you please add an example to the second paragraph?

Comment: I guess you need to provide your own schema when using `TOBAG`. Try `generate TOBAG(f1,f2,f3) as a:{(f1:long,f2:float,f3:int)}`.

Comment: the 2nd version (`cogroup`) generates _lists_ in the `json` output: `{"a":[{"f1":1,"f2":1.0}],...}` - note the extraneous `[]`.

Comment: I don't know how `JsonStorage` interprets the complex objects. If you `DESCRIBE grand` does it give you the schema you want? (The second method) If so, then you'll need to ask another question about how to get `JsonStorage` to do what you want...